# как выводить данные в javafx(поле Text)

Tags: java, javafx

Я новичок и только зашел в javaFX. я создал новый проект javaFX в Intelij IDEA, открыл sample.fxml в SceneBuilder  и вытащил /TextField/ и /Text/ теперь хочу чтобы число введенное в /TextField/ округлилось и отобразилось в /Text/. Типа "48.9999999 = 49", как выводить информацию в поле Text в IDEA.Желательно без нажатия по кнопке а сразу пока я ввожу число всё происходило.
И где можно почитать про всё подобное?

Comment: добавьте код...

Comment: Можете посмотреть здесь https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm

Comment: Ну, при нажатии на кнопку просто установите объекту Text нужный текст. С этим затруднения?

Comment: без кода сложно) кидай все сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы анализировать текст по мере ввода, вам нужен слушатель изменений.

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
        String oldValue, String newValue) {

    System.out.println(" Text Changed to  " + newValue + ")\n");
 }
});
```